# WPF - Animate ListBox.ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset?

Tags: wpf, animation, listbox, scrollviewer, horizontaloffset

I have a collection of `Visual`s in a `ListBox`. I need to find the `XPosition` of an element inside it and then animate the `HorizontalOffset` of the `ListBox`'s `ScrollViewer`.  Essentially I want to created an animated `ScrollIntoView` method.

This gives me a couple of problems.  Firstly, how can I get a reference to the `ListBox`s scrollviewer?  Secondly, how can i get the relative `XPosition` or `HozintalOfffset` of an arbitrary element in the `ListBox`?

I'm not reponding to any input on the `ListBox` itself so I can't use `Mouse` related properties.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to use a WPF storyboard for the animation because storyboards animate WPF dependency properties. You will need to call `ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(double)` to scroll.

You could try creating a custom dependency property that calls SetHorizontalOffset in the OnDependencyPropertyChanged() function. Then you could animate this property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollOffsetProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollOffset", typeof(double), typeof(YOUR_TYPE),
   new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnScrollOffsetChanged)));


public double ScrollOffset
{
   get { return (double)GetValue(ScrollOffsetProperty); }
   set { SetValue(ScrollOffsetProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnScrollOffsetChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
   YOUR_TYPE myObj = obj as YOUR_TYPE;

   if (myObj != null)
      myObj.SCROLL_VIEWER.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(myObj.ScrollOffset);
}
```

To get the scroll viewer you can use the VisualTreeHelper to search the visual children of the ListBox. Save a reference to the ScrollViewer because you will need it later. Try this:

```
public static childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
   where childItem : DependencyObject
{
   // Iterate through all immediate children
   for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
   {
      DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

      if (child != null && child is childItem)
         return (childItem)child;

      else
      {
         childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);

         if (childOfChild != null)
            return childOfChild;
      }
   }

   return null;
}
```

This function returns the first visual child of the parameter type. Call `FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(ListBox)` to get the ScrollViewer.

Finally, try using `UIElement.TranslatePoint(Point, UIElement)` to get the X position of the item. Call this function on the item, pass in 0,0 for the point, and pass in the ScrollViewer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My Lord, that's quite a job!  Thanks for the help Josh, it's pointed me in the right direction at least.

Comment: Do you mean ScrollToHorizontalOffset instead of SetHorizontalOffset?

Comment: Great idea. It helped me out!

Comment: It's possible that this property could be an attached DependencyProperty. That would allow this code to be reused on any control that has a ScrollView in it's visual tree.

Comment: You actually want to find the ItemsPresenter when translating the position of the item. e.g. 
  var itemContainer = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem);
  itemContainer.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), FindVisualChild<ItemsPresenter>(scrollViewer));

Comment: Thanks a lot to Josh! I wrote a behavior that listens for the PreviewKeyDown-Event on a ListBox and if the user pressed Ctrl+Key.Left or Ctrl+Key.Right the ScrollViewer of the ListBox should scroll to start or end. Finding the ScrollViewer worked like a charm with the VisualTreeHelper solution.

Comment: FindVisualChild method implements classical depth-first search; the comment is misleading.

Comment: That is correct. The point of the comment, however, was to clarify that the outer loop iterates through all of the item's children. Updated to remove the confusion about breadth-first since the recursive algorithm clearly is depth-first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if my method is good practice but for the limited time I had it seemed to work okay. Instead of using a story board I just used a DispatcherTimer instead.

```
ScrollLeftButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(
    o =>
       {
           var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)o;

           scrollTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

           scrollTimer.Start();

           scrollTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30);

           scrollTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
           {          
               scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset - 50);

               if (scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset <= 0)
               {
                   scrollTimer.Stop();
               }
           };
       });
```

Make sure it's a DispatchTimer so the thread is able to take control of the UI element

Also remember to bind to your object in your view!

```
<Button CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer }"
        Command="{Binding ScrollLeftButtonCommand }"/>
```