# Testing the scrollbar visibility of a ListBox in code-behind

Tags: wpf, listbox, scrollbar, visibility, code-behind

How to check whether the vertical scrollbar of the listbox is visible in code-behind?

I have a listbox with x:Name="listOfItems" and its underlying ScrollViewer's VerticalScrollbarVisibility is set to auto.

When the ItemsSource property of the ListBox is set, I want to check whether the verticalScrollbar is visible, but I don't know which property to check or how to dive into the scrollviewer element of the listbox.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find Listbox' ScrollViewer as described here: [WPF - Animate ListBox.ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665719/wpf-animate-listbox-scrollviewer-horizontaloffset/665798#665798)

Then you can use ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility property to check if the scrollbar is visible:

```
ScrollViewer sv = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(listOfItems);
Visibility scrollbarVisibility = sv.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility;
```