# Auto scroll on Drag And Drop: UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am developing UWP application. In one scenario, I am having multiple ListView on a canvas and I want to perform Drag and Drop between ListViews. While performing Drag-Drop scroller doesn't moves.

I tried to implement Behaviour defined in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316251/wpf-listbox-auto-scroll-while-dragging). But it is not working as `PreviewDragOver` event is not available in UWP.

Is there any way to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

While `PreviewDragOver` is not available in UWP, the `DragOver` event definitely is. It seems it should be possible to use this event in the attached behavior instead.