# WPF ListBox control horizontal scrolling in code

Tags: wpf, listbox, scroll

How can I set the horizontal scroll position of a list box in code? I have a list box with a wrap panel in the items template and I want to implement a 'page right' function that behaves like a page down down in a normal list but works sideways.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some more searching around the site, I figured out the answer to my question.

Using the following function from Josh G's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665719/wpf-animate-listbox-scrollviewer-horizontaloffset)

```
public static childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
{
     ...
}
```

With that function to page left and right via code, this is all you have to do is the following (where listBox is the name of my ListBox control),

```
void PageRight()
{
    ScrollViewer myScrollviewer = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(listBox);
    myScrollviewer.PageRight();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ScrollIntoView` method to scroll a specific item into view

Comment: How would you be able to tell if that was the first item that wasn't in view, so it could preform like a 'page down'? Thanks!