# Scroll ListBox up and down in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scroll

I can't find a ListBox methods for scrolling. I've found that **ListBox** itself implements **ScrollView** but I couldn't find **LineUp()** nor **LineDown()** method. Does ListBox have methods for scrolling ?

I need to attach this methods to buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling in WPF (for all controls that implement it) is done with the ScrollViewer. See the accepted answer in [WPF ListBox control horizontal scrolling in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556013/wpf-listbox-control-horizontal-scrolling-in-code) for how to find the ScrollViewer of your ListBox. Then you can use ScrollViewer's LineUp()/LineDown() methods or a whole host of methods on it.