# WPF - centering content in a scrollviewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a scrollviewer that contains a stackpanel of textblock items (actually, these are probably tabitems, I'm using a stackpanel inside a scrollviewer to override the default tabpanel in a tabcontrol template).  What I'd like to be able to do is, when the selected tab is changed, move the newly selected tab to the center of the scrollviewer's visible area.  Ideally this would work for all the tabs, even those on the far sides, but I would settle for being able to tell the scrollviewer to scroll such that a particular element is as close to centered as possible.

Are there any obvious ways to achieve this in WPF?  All the solutions I can think of right now involve a lot of work on custom controls.

[image]

Comment: @Robert Levy: That is not how it should be done, if no answer actually answers a question there is no need to accept any of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset()` is what you are looking for.  Just need to calculate what the offset of your selected element is relative to the stackpanel.   You can get that with something like `selectedElement.TranslatePoint( new Point(), stackPanel)`

To make this work for elements at the far ends, you'll need to add some 'blank' elements to the start and end of your scrollviewer to take up the appropriate amount of space.

To make this look pretty, call ScrollToHorizontalOffset in a timer to make the scrolling 'animate' instead of jump

Answer (score 19):

You can easily set the content to the center using the following code;

```
scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollviewer.ScrollableHeight / 2);
scrollviewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollviewer.ScrollableWidth / 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip.  I'm MVVM pattern and needed to keep an image centered while zooming. I simple used a command on my ScrollChanged event and passed my scrollviewer as parameter to the command. From there I was able to keep my content center from my ViewModel. Seems a bit of a hack though. I'll probably eventually create a custom scrollviewer that let's me do this via dependency properties.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
//for ScrollViewer s;
s.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((s.ExtentWidth - s.ViewportWidth) / 2);
s.ScrollToVerticalOffset((s.ExtentHeight - s.ViewportHeight) / 2);
```

Comment: In the WPF reference source you can see that ScrollableWidth = Math.Max(0.0, ExtentWidth - ViewportWidth) and likewise for height. So this is equivalent to the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9767075/3195477)

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question, you will need to calculate the space.

I recently had the same problem and I resolved it in that way.

So basically the first items and the last items will not move to the centre because they will be not scrolling for that (the count of items will depend on the ViewportWidth). So with that, we have the excludeMinZone and excludeMaxZone.
After we need to calculate the position of the **currently selected header**(item) in the StackPanel (scrollViewerTest.Content).
And with that, we calculate the offset needed to move to the centre.

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e){
double excludeMinZone = scrollViewerTest.ViewportWidth / 2;
double excludeMaxZone = scrollViewerTest.ExtentWidth - (scrollViewerTest.ViewportWidth / 2);

double centerPositionXAbsolute = item.TranslatePoint(new Point(), scrollViewerTest.Content as UIElement).X + (item.ActualWidth / 2);

double horizontalOffset = centerPositionXAbsolute <= excludeMinZone
    ? 0
    : centerPositionXAbsolute >= excludeMaxZone ? scrollViewerTest.ScrollableWidth : centerPositionXAbsolute - excludeMinZone;

scrollViewerTest.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(horizontalOffset);
}}
```

To add smooth animation, you can follow this answer ( [Animate ListBox.ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/665798))