# Animation for ScrollViewer vertical offset

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, offset, scrollviewer

I want to animate vertical scrolling of ScrollViewer.
As I understand it the only way to get this event

```
private void viewer_ScrollChanged (object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
```

And within a handler to start the animation.
But in this case, the handler will be called at each step of the animation.
How do I distinguish the animation process from such PageUp?

Maybe there is some better way to override the changes in the vertical offset?

Comment: Perhaps duplicate question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665719/wpf-animate-listbox-scrollviewer-horizontaloffset

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you'd probably have to create a custom control for that.

Fortunately, it has been done [here](http://matthiasshapiro.com/2009/05/06/how-to-create-an-animated-scrollviewer-or-listbox-in-wpf/). I've tried it (long time ago) and it works. Oh, I see that there is/are ready-made DLL to download from the page, so you don't have to create it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear on what you're trying to do - but I'm guessing that you only want to animate when the user moves the scroll bar with the mouse - so how about handling MouseDown on ScrollViewer (record what the position is) and handle MouseUp, if there was scroll do your animation?

I think using mouseup/down in this case is fine as you don't want the animation for general scrolling?

Comment: Everything is as you describe.
But I would like to animate all possible situations. (Mouse Wheel, Home, End etc)
And not to calculating the required offset.
Ie just animate all type of offsets.