# Animate (smoothly) ScrollViewer programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to smoothly animate a `ScrollViewer`s vertical offset in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime?

I have tried using the `ScrollViewer.ChangeView()` method and the change of vertical offset is not animated no matter if I set the `disableAnimation` parameter to true or false.

For example: `myScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, myScrollViewer.VerticalOffset + p, null, false);`
The offset is changed without animation.

I also tried using a vertical offset mediator:

```
/// <summary>
/// Mediator that forwards Offset property changes on to a ScrollViewer
/// instance to enable the animation of Horizontal/VerticalOffset.
/// </summary>
public sealed class ScrollViewerOffsetMediator : FrameworkElement
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScrollViewer instance to forward Offset changes on to.
    /// </summary>
    public ScrollViewer ScrollViewer
    {
        get { return (ScrollViewer)GetValue(ScrollViewerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollViewerProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollViewerProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollViewer",
            typeof(ScrollViewer),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnScrollViewerChanged));
    private static void OnScrollViewerChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)(e.NewValue);
        if (null != scrollViewer)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(mediator.VerticalOffset);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// VerticalOffset property to forward to the ScrollViewer.
    /// </summary>
    public double VerticalOffset
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalOffsetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("VerticalOffset",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnVerticalOffsetChanged));
    public static void OnVerticalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        if (null != mediator.ScrollViewer)
        {
            mediator.ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double)(e.NewValue));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Multiplier for ScrollableHeight property to forward to the ScrollViewer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// 0.0 means "scrolled to top"; 1.0 means "scrolled to bottom".
    /// </remarks>
    public double ScrollableHeightMultiplier
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScrollableHeightMultiplierProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollableHeightMultiplierProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollableHeightMultiplierProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollableHeightMultiplier",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnScrollableHeightMultiplierChanged));
    public static void OnScrollableHeightMultiplierChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        var scrollViewer = mediator.ScrollViewer;
        if (null != scrollViewer)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double)(e.NewValue) * scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

and I can animate the `VerticalOffset` property with `DoubleAnimation`:

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
da.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
da.From = Mediator.ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
da.To = da.From + p;
da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
da.EasingFunction = new ExponentialEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
Storyboard.SetTarget(da, Mediator);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, "(Mediator.VerticalOffset)");
sb.Children.Add(da);

sb.Begin();
```

Mediator is declared in XAML.
But this animation is not smooth on my device (Lumia 930).

Comment: One thing you could try is [`WinRTXamlToolkit`'s `ScrollToVerticalOffsetWithAnimation` extension](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Extensions/ScrollViewerExtensions.cs). You can implement it manually or add the library via Nuget.

Comment: I don't think, there is a way to make it completely smooth. This kind of animation probably isn't hardware accelerated.

Comment: No... http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.fi/2013/04/smooth-scrolling-content-on-windows.html ?

Comment: @MikkoVitala First of all with this method you lose virtualization, because you put a ListBox inside a ScrollViewer. this sample was for WP8.0, and I had implemented the same behavior too, but in WP8 this works smoothly because there is no concept of Dependent and Independent animations, all animations are independent and run on the composition thread. In WP8.1 dependent animations run on the UI thread and therefore you lose the smooth animation. But anyways, thanks for the link.

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this?

Comment: Don't have an answer myself, but felt like starting a bounty on this question to see if we can get it answered.

Comment: @Kirstian Vukusic you didn't say whether or not the first comment helped. What is the issue with WinRT extension?

Comment: Can you give me an example where `ChangeView` doesn't do the animation? It should animate regardless of whether virtualization is on or not.

Comment: In my project I am using the `ScrollViewer` of a `ListView` and it never animates. Maybe I have too complex DataTemplates, but I doubt it, because the scrolling is very smooth, just the programatical scrolling is not. When I use `ChangeView`, it just changes the vertical offset without animation.

Comment: Kristian, how about Justin's answer below?  Did it work for you?  I'd like to give him the bounty if his answer took care of this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a busy week... but it worked because of the Task.Delay which I didn't know would solve the problem. Anyways, thanks for starting the bounty which speed up obtaining the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should stick with `ChangeView` for scrolling animations regardless of whether data virtualization is on or not.

Without seeing your code where the `ChangeView` doesn't work, it's a bit hard to guess what's really going on but there are a couple of things that you can try.

First approach is to add a `Task.Delay(1)` before calling `ChangeView`, just to give the OS some time to finish off other concurrent UI tasks.

```
await Task.Delay(1);
scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight, null, false);
```

The second approach is a bit more complex. What I've noticed is that, when you have many complex items in the `ListView`, the scrolling animation from the first item to the last (from the `ChangeView` method) isn't very smooth at all.

This is because the `ListView` first needs to realize/render many items along the way due to data virtualization and then does the animated scrolling. Not very efficient IMHO.

What I came up with is this - First, use a non-animated `ListView.ScrollIntoView` to scroll to the last item just to get it realized. Then, call `ChangeView` to move the offset up to a size of the `ActualHeight * 2` of the `ListView` with animation disabled (you can change it to whatever size you want based on your app's scrolling experience). Finally, call `ChangeView` again to scroll back to the end, with animation this time. Doing this will give a much better scrolling experience 'cause the scrolling distance is just the `ActualHeight` of the `ListView`.

Keep in mind that when the item you want to scroll to is already realized on the UI, you don't want to do anything above. You simply just calculate the distance between this item and the top of the `ScrollViewer` and call `ChangeView` to scroll to it.

I already wrapped the logic above in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32559623/231837)'s **Update 2** section (thanks to this question I realized my initial answer doesn't work when virtualization is on :p). Let me know how you go.

Comment: The first approach made the `ChangeView` smooth, because of the `Task.Delay`. I had no idea this would help so much. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I think that question has already been answered here:

[Animated (Smooth) scrolling on ScrollViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731402/animated-smooth-scrolling-on-scrollviewer)

There is also the WinRT XAML Toolki, which provides "a way to scroll a ScrollViewer to specified offset with animation":

http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: When you look at the source of [ScrollViewerExtensions.cs](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Extensions/ScrollViewerExtensions.cs), the method which creates the animation is with the name `ScrollToVerticalOffsetWithAnimation`, and you can see the line `da.EnableDependentAnimation = true` which means that the animation is not run on the composition thread, which means that it may not run smooth, and this is the main question, how to animate the scrollviewer with **independent animations**

Comment: Neither of those are relevant to WinRT/Windows10

Answer (score 0):

With ScrollToVerticalOffset deprecated/obsolete in newer builds of Windows 10 (leaving the ScrollViewOffSetMediator extension control no longer working), and the new ChangeView method not actually providing smooth or controllable animation, a new solution is needed.  Please see my answer here which allows one to *smoothly* animate and zoom the ScrollViewer and its contents to any desired position, regardless of where the application's end user has the scrollbars initially positioned:

[How to scroll to element in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190237/how-to-scroll-to-element-in-uwp/45424406#45424406)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1255753/WPF-Easiest-Way-to-Create-a-Animated-Smoothed-Scro) is what you're looking for and it seems the method he used is working for you.

**Quick Way:**

1. Add offset dependency parameter manually to **scrollviewer**.
2. Duplicate your scrollviewer
3. Use an animator.