# In page navigation with buttons xaml/c# UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, uwp

I'm working on creating a Windows 10 Universal app that has a fixed header with three buttons across the top. Each button would bring the user to a certain place on the page. Basically what anchoring does in HTML. Is this possible with Xaml/C#? Any ideas on how this would work would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been answered before, here is a solution about how to scroll to the certain place. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190237/how-to-scroll-to-element-in-uwp/32193216#32193216) would be helpful to you .

You may use `MyScrollView.ChangeView(null, abosulatePosition.Y, null, true);` or `MyScrollView.ScrollToElement(otherTb);`

Comment: Thanks! This worked!