# Scroll to object on Button click (C# /Xaml)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there a way to have a xaml page scroll to a particular object on a button click? For example, I have three buttons at the top of my page. I would like each button to move the scrollviewer to the top, middle, and bottom section of the page. How can I make this happen? Thanks!

Comment: I'd venture to guess you could just do a property change to the ScrollViewer VerticalOffset. Just take like 0 for top, content height size / 2 for middle, and content size height for bottom for example.

Comment: I think you want something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190237/how-to-scroll-to-element-in-uwp/32193216#32193216).

Answer (score 1):

I try to create the Xaml and to solve the problem. This is my solution.
This is the Xaml code.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
       <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Top" Click="Button_Click" ></Button>
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Center" Click="Button_Click_1" ></Button><Button Content="Botton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click_2" ></Button>
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Name="MyScrollViewer" MaxZoomFactor="9">
     <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Name="TextBlock" Height="20"> </TextBlock>
          <Rectangle Height="300" Width="100"  Fill="BlanchedAlmond"></Rectangle>
          <Rectangle Height="300" Width="100"  Fill="Blue"></Rectangle>
          <Rectangle Height="300" Width="100"  Fill="BlueViolet"></Rectangle>
          <Rectangle Height="300" Width="100"  Fill="Chartreuse"></Rectangle>
          <Rectangle Height="300" Width="100"  Fill="Crimson"></Rectangle>
     </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And this is the .cs Code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollableHeight = MyScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
    var height= scrollableHeight / 2;
    MyScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(height);
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(MaxHeight);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the response, this didn't work for me though. Nothing happens on the button clicks.

Comment: @robbiestells The code has been updated ,  I have tested and it works well.