# Bringing a specific conrol into view

Tags: xaml, uwp

In my UWP app I am trying to do custom validation. There are several `TextBox`es inside a `ContentDialog` and the primary button of this `ContentDialog` acts as the submit button of this form (group of many text boxes). If there if something wrong, then I put focus on that control.

For example, if I have a `TextBox Name="FirstName"` and the value inside this element fails validation, I do this.

```
FirstName.Text = string.Empty;
FirstName.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

When doing this in a mobile it scrolls up to the `FirstName` TextBlock if it is not in view ( because the touch keyboard opens up with focus inside `TextBlock` )

But in a desktop, doing

```
FirstName.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

does put the focus on the TextBlock but there is no scrolling up ( If it is not in view ). So I tried using this line of code :

```
FirstName.StartBringIntoView();
```

BUT THIS DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK.

However, I made it work using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190237/how-to-scroll-to-element-in-uwp) , I was wondering what is the purpose of `BringIntoView` or if I am using it wrong.

Comment: You need to share your xaml where the `ScrollViewer` and `TextBox` are defined.

Comment: I see, it doesn't work with `StackPanel` but works well with grids

Comment: hmm interesting... I don't think this is the right behavior though.

Comment: Just realized that I was actually the one who gave the answer that you linked lol...

Comment: almost all my questions are answered by you :)

Comment: Haha, pleasure. Back to your question though, if changing the panel type solved your issue, maybe worth raising it with the UI team 'cause this feels like a bug to me. You can file a bug report [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/issues).