# How to set ScrollViewer VerticalOffset property for Storyboard Animation (Windows Universal App)?

Tags: c#, uwp, storyboard, windows-10-universal, scrollviewer

I tried to make storyboard animation but I couldn't change ScrollViewer's VerticalOffset property. This code works very well with Opacity ect. properties but not with VerticalOffset and HorizontalOffset.

```
private void MakeVerticalAnimation()
{
    Storyboard AnimationStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation VerticalOffsetAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    Storyboard.SetTarget(VerticalOffsetAnimation, MyScrollViewer);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(VerticalOffsetAnimation, "VerticalOffset");
    VerticalOffsetAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
    VerticalOffsetAnimation.From = 100;
    VerticalOffsetAnimation.To = 0;
    VerticalOffsetAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    AnimationStoryboard.Children.Add(VerticalOffsetAnimation);
    AnimationStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation won't work because `VerticalOffset` is *read-only*. You can use the `ChangeView` method instead.

```
MyScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, 0, null, false);
```

Have a look at my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190237/how-to-scroll-to-element-in-uwp).

Comment: Oh...Silly me. Any way to edit ScrollViewer template to adjust scroll speed. At the moment speed is just too fast for my purpose. Looks like that I need to find other solution for my problem.