# ScrollIntoView property not working for gridview in windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, scrollview, windows-10-universal

I tried this below code:

XAML Code:

```
<GridView x:Name="listgrid">
 <GridView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel Margin="15,15,0,0">
       <Image Height="170" Width="170" Source="{Binding}"></Image>
     </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
 </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

Cs code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
{
   list.Add("ms-appx:///Images/A-aa.jpg");
}
listgrid.ItemsSource = list;
listgrid.ScrollIntoView(listgrid.Items[30]);
```

I above code to scroll view to my selected item, but it's not showing any changes, i think i used this property in a wrong way any one please help me to scroll to gridview position.

Comment: any once please help me to find the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replied your same question in MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d0a772b3-80b9-4a11-92a9-89963c29a52f/scrollintoview-property-not-working-for-gridview-in-windows-10-universal-app?forum=wpdevelop

You need to have something more to distinguish items, for example, give every image a name since items you bind to GridView are same, ScrollIntoView default find the first one.

And commonly you need to set a height property for the GridView.

For more complex requirements, there is a good thread you can reference:
[Windows 10 ScrollIntoView() is not scrolling to the items in the middle of a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557216/windows-10-scrollintoview-is-not-scrolling-to-the-items-in-the-middle-of-a-lis)

Comment: when i change my code as you suggest Listgrid_Loaded event not firing..

Answer (score 0):

Try to subscribe on `Loaded` event and call `ScrollIntoView` inside event handler:

```
listgrid.Loaded += Listgrid_Loaded;

....
private void Listgrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listgrid.ScrollIntoView(listgrid.Items[30]);
}
```

Comment: yes, but my code calls when control loaded. it's difference in internal control state.

Comment: sorry..., i didn't get what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void Gridview_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ShellPage.Current.SelectedRecItem != null)
        {
            this.gridview.SelectedItem = ShellPage.Current.SelectedRecItem;
            this.gridview.UpdateLayout();
            this.gridview.ScrollIntoView(ShellPage.Current.SelectedRecItem);
        }
    }
```