# Can I sync scrolling between multiple Listview items in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

How can I link 2 Listview components, so that their scrolling is in sync (when I scroll one, the other scrolls too at the same time)?

So basically I need a way to:

1) Monitor the scrolling event of Listview1
2) Set the same scrolling offset to Listview2

I found some examples here on Stackoverflow but they either refer to WPF, or WinRT and they are not compatible with my app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have described in your question can be done by the following steps:

1. Find the `ScrollViewer` inside the `ListView` (check out `GetScrollViewer` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557216/windows-10-scrollintoview-is-not-scrolling-to-the-items-in-the-middle-of-a-lis)).
2. Subscribe to the `ViewChanged` event.
3. Inside the event handler, call `ChangeView` on the other `ScrollViewer`.

Assume you are scrolling vertically -

```
private void SyncScrollViewers()
{
    var scrollViewer1 = MyListView1.GetScrollViewer();
    var scrollViewer2 = MyListView2.GetScrollViewer();

    scrollViewer1.ViewChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        scrollViewer2.ChangeView(null, scrollViewer1.VerticalOffset, null, false);
    };
}
```