# Synced 2 ListView ScrollViewer together. How to stop firing events multiple time?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I finally managed to sync two ListViews I had together so I'm able to scroll both at the same time.

I used the `GetScrollViewer()` method from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32559623/9102905) and the sync method from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296375/9102905).

Now I want to be able to scroll either of the two ListViews but when I just add another event like this:

```
private void SyncScrollViewers()
    {
        var scrollViewer1 = ListViewOne.GetScrollViewer();
        var scrollViewer2 = ListViewTwo.GetScrollViewer();

        if (scrollViewer1 == null || scrollViewer2 == null) return;

        scrollViewer1.ViewChanged += (s, e) =>
        {                
            scrollViewer2.ChangeView(null, scrollViewer1.VerticalOffset, null, false);
        };

        scrollViewer2.ViewChanged += (s, e) =>
        {  
            scrollViewer1.ChangeView(null, scrollViewer2.VerticalOffset, null, false);
        };
    }
```

It just keeps repeating the events.
When I scroll `ScrollViewer1` it fires the scroll event for `ScrollViewer2` and when that one scrolls it fires the event for `ScrollViewer1` again.
Which makes scrolling the ListViews a rather wobbly sight.

Is there any way to stop the second event of firing when the sender is either `ScrollViewer1`or `ScrollViewer2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your this way to register both [ViewChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_ViewChanged) event of `scrollViewer1` and `scrollViewer2`, the [ViewChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_ViewChanged) event of each ScrollViewer will trigger when manipulations such as scrolling and zooming have caused the view to change.

But you can operate the [ViewChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_ViewChanged) event handler to decide whether or when the ScrollViewer should scroll again as the following code.

```
private bool ScrollViewer1Scrolled, ScrollViewer2Scrolled;
private void SyncScrollViewers()
{
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer1 = ListViewOne.GetScrollViewer();
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer2 = ListViewTwo.GetScrollViewer();

    if (scrollViewer1 == null || scrollViewer2 == null) return;
    scrollViewer1.ViewChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        ScrollViewer1Scrolled = true;
        if (!ScrollViewer2Scrolled)
        {
            scrollViewer2.ChangeView(null, scrollViewer1.VerticalOffset, null, false);
            Debug.WriteLine("scrollViewer2 scrolled");
        }
        ScrollViewer2Scrolled = false;
    };

    scrollViewer2.ViewChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        ScrollViewer2Scrolled = true;
        if (!ScrollViewer1Scrolled)
        {
            scrollViewer1.ChangeView(null, scrollViewer2.VerticalOffset, null, false);
            Debug.WriteLine("scrollViewer1 scrolled");
        }
        ScrollViewer1Scrolled = false;
    };
}
```