# How to create an automatic animated carousel so content inside a GridView with DataTemplates starts scrolling using C# or XAML?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want my content inside my GridView to scroll when I start my storyboard. Right now the storyboard targets the gridview and not the content. How do I make it to scroll inside the gridview?

This is how my Storyboards and DataTemplates look like:

```
<Page.Resources    
 <Storyboard x:Key="CarouselStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="CarouselTransform" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"/>
 </Storyboard>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CatTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Margin="30,0,30,0" Background="Red">

        </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="DogTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Margin="30,0,30,0" Background="Green">

        </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

And this is how my Griview looks like:

```
<GridView x:Name="myGridView" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">

        <GridView.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="CarouselTransform" />
        </GridView.RenderTransform>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>

</GridView>
<Button Click="Left_Click" Content="Left" Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left"Width="405"/>
```

And this is how I start my storyboard using some C#

```
  private int currentElement = 0;

    private void Left_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentElement < 100)
        {
            currentElement++;
            AnimateCarousel();
        }
    }
    private void AnimateCarousel()
    {
        Storyboard storyboard =  (this.Resources["CarouselStoryboard"] as Storyboard);
        DoubleAnimation animation = storyboard.Children.First() as DoubleAnimation;
        animation.To = -200 * currentElement;
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: It's a WPF app or UWP app? Can you clarify your tag first?

Comment: Sorry, it's a UWP app

Answer (score 0):

First of all, directly animate attach propery will not work due to we are lack of a reasonable built-in attached property:

1. What is [scrollview in control template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/scroll-controls#scrollviewer-in-a-control-template):

It's typical for a ScrollViewer control to exist as a composite part of other controls. A ScrollViewer part, along with the ScrollContentPresenter class for support, will display a viewport along with scrollbars only when the host control's layout space is being constrained smaller than the expanded content size. This is often the case for lists, ***so ListView and GridView templates always include a ScrollViewer***.

2. To influence some of the behavior and properties that are from within the ScrollViewer part, ScrollViewer defines a number of XAML attached properties:

   - ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange
   - ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility
   - ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode
   - ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled
   - ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled
   - ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled
   - ScrollViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled
   - ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled
   - ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled
   - ScrollViewer.IsZoomChainingEnabled
   - ScrollViewer.IsZoomInertiaEnabled
   - ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility
   - ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode
   - ScrollViewer.ZoomMode
3. [Animating XAML attached properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations#animating-xaml-attached-properties):We can only animate built-in attached properties.

So instead of the above idea we need to get the ScrollView embeded in GridView first:

1. Create your own GridView

   ```
   public class MyGridView:GridView
   {
    private ScrollViewer myscrollviewer;

    public ScrollViewer MyScrollViewer
    {
       get { return myscrollviewer; }
       set { myscrollviewer = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
       base.OnApplyTemplate();
       ScrollViewer testscrollviewer = GetTemplateChild("ScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
       myscrollviewer = testscrollviewer;
    }
   }
   ```
2. Use it in your XAML:

   ```
   <local:MyGridView x:Name="mygv".../>
   ```
3. Here since VerticalOffset is readonly, I cannot use DoubleAnimation to animate the scrollview. Thanks to Justin ***he has shared this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557216/windows-10-scrollintoview-is-not-scrolling-to-the-items-in-the-middle-of-a-lis/32559623#32559623)***. With the help of [ScrollView.ChangeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.changeview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_ChangeView_Windows_Foundation_IReference_System_Double__Windows_Foundation_IReference_System_Double__Windows_Foundation_IReference_System_Single__) we can have some animation.
   And a more simple way if you don't need the animation:

   ```
    mygv.ScrollIntoView(mygv.Items[10], ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Leading);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. But I can't get it to work. Nothing happens now when I click the button. I'm not sure how I can implement the code in my project

Comment: @LittleBird Any details about what you have done? Which way is chose by you to animate the scroll behavior? With or without animation?