# ScrollViewer scroll item into center

Tags: c#, uwp, center, scrollviewer, custom-scrolling

In C# UWP I need to bring item into center of ScrollViewer/ListView, instead of top or bottom.

I use this code to scroll:

```
listViewMain.ScrollIntoView(ItemsList[50]);
```

Any extension method or some other way to achieve this?

Comment: this would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002013/2630817

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 ScrollIntoView() is not scrolling to the items in the middle of a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557216/windows-10-scrollintoview-is-not-scrolling-to-the-items-in-the-middle-of-a-lis)