# Scroll to selected item in NavigationView UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need to Scroll `NavigationView` to its `SelectedItem`. In which I tried below methods one with `TryMoveFocusAsync` and another by tring to get `ScrollViewer` through parent of the `SelectedItem` from `SelectionChanged` event. But, the parent seems to be null.

Note: NavigationView doesn't have `ScrollIntoView` like `ListView`

**1st Method**

```
   private async void OnSelectionChanged(
         NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
   {
        if (args.SelectedItem is NavigationViewItem item)
        {
           FocusManager.TryFocusAsync(
                    sender.SelectedItem as DependencyObject,
                    FocusState.Pointer);
           ViewModel.NavigateTo(item.Name);
         }
         UpdateBackButton();
   }
```

**2nd Method**

```
   private async void OnSelectionChanged(
        NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
```

`(args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem).Parent` returns null.

Is there a way to scroll the `NavigationViewMenuItem` to its selected index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `ScrollIntoView` convenience method is not available outside of `ListView` it is a bit more work to get this done. First we need to write a helper method that finds the parent of a `DependencyObject` using the `VisualTreeHelper`:

```
private T FindParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject item)
{
    while (item != null)
    {
        item = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
        if (item is T expectedParent)
        {
            return expectedParent;
        }
    }
    return default;
}
```

Now using this, we first find the `ScrollViewer` (which should be a grand-parent of the `NavigationViewItem`):

```
var scrollViewer = FindParentOfType<ScrollViewer>(item);
```

We now need to find out the position of this menu item within the scroll viewer, which can be done using `TransformToVisual` and `TransformPoint`. Knowing this vertical location we can now scroll to it using `ScrollViewer.ChangeView` method:

```
if (scrollViewer != null)
{
    var transform = 
         item.TransformToVisual(scrollViewer)
             .TransformPoint(new Point(0,0));
    scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, transform.Y, null);
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped, @Vignesh! Happy coding!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with longer lists where the system already virtualizes the non-visible parts of the list (longer here means above a few dozen items, not something really very long). Those items have to be realized first for the position to be valid.

Comment: It should be possible to use `ListViewBase.ScrollIntoView`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.scrollintoview?view=winrt-19041

Comment: Hardly, considering that `NavigationView` isn't based on `ListViewBase`. Right now I'm trying to adapt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557216/windows-10-scrollintoview-is-not-scrolling-to-the-items-in-the-middle-of-a-lis and I'm mostly there but not yet. If it works, I'll post the solution.

Comment: The old NavigationView template contains a NavigationViewListView control, which derives from ListView, so the method can be called on it. The new one in WinUI is based on ItemsRepeater, so there I am not sure how to do this yet 

Comment: Now that you mention it, this might be of some help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/items-repeater#bringing-an-element-into-view