# Smooth scrollTo in WebView UWP

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, smooth-scrolling

scrollTo in WebView UWP may be achieved through:

```
private string ScrollToTopString = @"window.scrollTo(0,0);";
private async void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await WebViewTest.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { ScrollToTopString });
}
```

But what about animated/Smooth scrolling in WebView UWP? In Android that is achieved either officially or through variations (for example, using android.animation.ObjectAnimator), whereas in UWP only ScrollViewer seems to support it as far as I know. [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190237/how-to-scroll-to-element-in-uwp/32193216#32193216) [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198000/animate-smoothly-scrollviewer-programatically)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't animate the `WebView` because the `WebView` itself isn't actually scrolling, just like your browser doesn't actually scroll; it's the "window" element that's scrolling.

However, if I understand what you're wanting correctly, just replace your `ScrollToTopString` with this:

```
var ScrollToTopString = @"var int = setInterval(function() { 
window.scrollBy(0, -5);

if( window.pageYOffset === 0 )
    clearInterval(int);
}, 1);";
```

This will scroll that "window" element I mentioned. You can raise the speed of the interval (I have it set to 1) to slow down the animation, or lower the value of `scrollBy` to make it go faster.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for clarifying terms and for helping me. It's all about the ["window" object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp).