# Is it possible to create Windows 10 desktop apps with list boxes that scroll smoothly like they do on macOS?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, windows-10

I am doing a couple of demo apps on Windows 10, having not done any Windows development for a couple of years and am struggling to figure out how to make list boxes that scroll smoothly when using a touchpad or mouse.  It seems the only way to prevent jumping one row at a time is if you use the mouse to drag the scroll bar.  Some of the list view items are quite tall so this results in a terrible user experience.

I am puzzled that this is even an option at all but it seems there is no easy way to change this behaviour to pixel level scrolling.  I notice that even Visual Studio's editor and lists seems to also have a minimum scrolling height of one line or row.

Currently I am using C#/WPF - please tell me there is some easy way to fix this - is there any good reason for this behaviour - surely todays computer hardware can easily handle smooth scrolling ?  Why is this not an issue on macOS ?  Would love to hear the explanation.

Are UWP apps also stuck with this issue?

EDIT:

I have tried setting `CanScrollContent=False` and `VirtualisingPanel.ScrollUnit=Pixel` to no avail. These seem to improve things somewhat and the views no longer scroll row by row but scrolling amount is still variable depending on the content of the ScrollView or ListView.

OK I have just built a sample UWP app and can confirm that both the ListView and the ListBox appear to give smooth scrolling right out of the box with no additional effort required on my part.

Comment: and [Animated (Smooth) scrolling on ScrollViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731402/animated-smooth-scrolling-on-scrollviewer/20846310) also

Comment: You can use UWP for development. With UWP you can feel smooth scrolling and different option on your problem

Comment: Thanks Stefan and bradbury9 - from what I can tell it IS NOT POSSIBLE to have smooth scrolling on WPF ListView or ScrollView without doing some major coding.  I hope I am wrong about this - it seems really odd that smooth scrolling doesn't come for free as the default behaviour.

Comment: not sure why this is marked as having been answered at the link above as there is no accepted answer on that question